# Problem with python looping when I have no loop in my code

Tags: python-3.x

I have a main program that calls some modules. For some reason when I run the code it loops over parts of the main code when there is no loop in the code.

```
import os
import datetime
import multiprocessing as mp
import shutil

#make temp folder for data files
date = str(datetime.datetime.now())
date = date[0:19]
date = date.replace(':', '-')
temp_folder_name = 'temp_data_files_' + date
os.mkdir(temp_folder_name)

#make folder for sim files
date = str(datetime.datetime.now())
date = date[0:19]
date = date.replace(':', '-')
save_folder_name = 'Sim_files_' + date
os.mkdir(save_folder_name)

#make data files and save in temp folder
import make
make.data('model_1',temp_folder_name) #model name and folder for results

#run file on multiple cores
import distributed
corecount = mp.cpu_count() # edit this value to the number of cores you want to use on your computer
if __name__ == '__main__':
    distributed.simulate(temp_folder_name, corecount ,save_folder_name)
```

The program should make two folders. It then uses 'make' to make some files and put them in the temp folder. It then should use 'distributed' to do some things with the files and save them in the 'sim_files' folder. But for some reason it makes several folders in each instance (with slightly different time stamps).
The distributed function includes some links but I don't think these should have an effect on the main program.
The `if __name__ == ...` line is to do with multiprocessing a guard against infinitely looping

Comment: Please make a [mre]

Comment: Hi, I have reduced it as much as I thought suitable. The bits making the folders are important because otherwise you can't see that it makes the same folder 5 times.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to this. It is to do with the way multiprocessing works, the child processes import the main program like modules. This lead to the main program being run for each instance of multiprocessing.
The solution is to move the `if __name__ == '__main__':` line to the start of the main. This ensures that it only runs when it is being called as itself, rather than when it is imported like a module :)